# Issue with python's Numba, no module llvmlite.binding

Tags: python, numba

There is extensive documentation out there about Numba, and the llvm compiler.
What I did so far on my OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

```
pip install numba

brew install llvm
```

so far, so good. But I cannot get around this error message when I import numba

```
import numba
```

[image: error message]

I tried to pull the git repository of [llvmlite](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite) and set it up but to no avail. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, which was resolved by installing llvm using `conda install llvmlite` and numba using `conda install numba`.

Answer (score -1):

StackOverflow in not a replacement for a project issue tracker. It seems that this bug was already raise at:

https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/55